# How to Delete a file using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i write the code in asp.net using c# to delete the file in my computer, but it is not deleting please help me thank u. this is my code, i write in button click event

```
        string path = "E:\\sasi\\delt.doc";
        FileInfo myfileinf = new FileInfo(path);
        myfileinf.Delete();
```

Comment: 1) You aren't trying to delete a file in the client side using ASP.NET code are you? 2) Checking myfileInf.Exists would help. 3) You should show us the Delete exception because I don't think it's not throwing one

Comment: ya i am trying to delete a file

Comment: Surya, ClientSide or ServerSide? You keep us in the dark.

Comment: sorry Mr. Henk Holterman i want to delete server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the ASP user has permissions to this folder. By default this user is not given access to much of the harddrive..

Answer (score 5):

```
public void DeleteFileFromFolder(string StrFilename)
{

    string strPhysicalFolder = Server.MapPath("..\\");

    string strFileFullPath = strPhysicalFolder + StrFilename;

    if (IO.File.Exists(strFileFullPath)) {
        IO.File.Delete(strFileFullPath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to delete a file you must ensure that the account has sufficient permissions. In general ASP.NET applications run under limited permission account such as `Network Service`. For example if your application runs under IIS 6 you could go to the Administration Console and set a custom account in the application pool properties:

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb969101.SharePoint_SQL_TshootingFig3%28en-US,SQL.90%29.jpg](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb969101.SharePoint_SQL_TshootingFig3%28en-US,SQL.90%29.jpg)

You need to ensure that the account is member of the `IIS_WPG` group.

Comment: Where is this located in IIS 8